# Use async pipe just to handle observable

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Is it bad practice to use an async pipe in the template just so Angular handles the observable?

e.g.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="observable$ | async"></ng-container>
<div>
  <ng-template #container></ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats the observables job? Don't you need its values?

Comment: @tkausl my guess is, that the logic goes in a `tap` operator.

Comment: I tap into it to add a dynamic component.

Comment: What's the point of the question here? How can it be a bad practice to use a built in feature of Angular. Is there some thing more you're trying to ask.

Comment: I wouldn't do it like this. Just subscribe and unsubscribe in OnDestroy

Comment: I'm just not sure if that's causing issues i'm unaware of. I haven't seen it used like that before so just want to make sure there's not something I'm not aware of.

Comment: I have, it works well and it has its advantages (handling the subscription + angular team got you covered when using `OnPush`). but the readability is a big concern here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it bad practice to use an async pipe in the template

Practices are very subjective. Generally, in the history of StackOverflow I've told more people as answers to use `async` instead of *subscribing* inside the component. That doesn't make it better, but often people don't write good code to handle observables inside the component.

> just so Angular handles the observable?

It's not *handling* the observable. It's *drying* the component.

A *dry component* is one that doesn't have any internal business logic, and the templates render the *state* of the component. This results is a *much easier* component to test since there is no internal state that requires mutation and broad range of tests to verify that business logic.

So how does that work with *async*?

You move the business logic to *services*, and *test* the services isolated from the *presentation* layer.

So here's a simple example:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    user$: Observable<User>;

    // more business logic
}

@Component({
   template: `
      <div *ngIf="user$ | async as user">
          {{user.name}}
      </div>
   `
})
export class UserComponent {
    user$: Observable<User>;

    constructor(auth: AuthService) {
        this.user$ = auth.user$;
    }
}
```

With the above example we have *business logic* of the user authentication service, and a *presentation* component for that user. We can test the `AuthService` isolated from the component and focus on testing the business logic. Alternatively, we can simply verify snapshots of the component's rendered view as tests. The `UserComponent` has no internal logic, and doesn't require any assertions about it's state. We only have to verify the rendering.

Generally, people separate their authentication from their components because authentication is re-usable. So maybe the above isn't the best example, but the key here is that Angular allows you to use observables extensively in your application to *separate* the business logic from presentation. The `asycn` pipe has the effect of turning *dynamic data* into a *dry template*. So while the observables emit changes and the pipe updates the view. We can still think of the template as being dry.

I often refer to components that use nothing buy `async` pipes and observables without having any *subscribe* calls as being **reactive components**. Since they utilize reactive programming practices. You'll find components like these along side reactive libraries like NgRx, Redux, NgXS which all offer you extensive features to build applications along this style.

Comment: I appreciate the response. In this situation the logic will either go into the tap operator or in subscribe since I'm adding a dynamic component to the container. I'm adding and removing the dynamic component on a timer with different data.

Comment: Great points. If someone's filling their components with state, they're not taking full advantage of Angular with RxJS. Beyond just the separation of business and presentation logic, stateless components (and services) are just more robust because there's so much less potential for unintended side effects when adding new features. In my experience it might take a little longer up front to write a stateless component, but I spend much less time debugging and testing later.

Comment: @DavidSpeirs I didn't read in your question that you were adding business logic by tapping the observable. You should update your question with code examples of what you're doing.

Comment: @Reactgular It's in the comments currently. I didn't add it initially because I didn't really think it was relevant. The question I have is about using the async pipe in the template when you're not using the data there. I'm just not sure if that has any negative effects I'm not aware of.

Comment: @DavidSpeirs people use `async` in templates when they don't use the data all the time. Especially when conditionally showing content `<div *ngIf="showSidebar$ | async">SIDEBAR</div>`. You can also use `async` to delay showing of content until the internal state of a component is ready. For example; a spinner to show Http request is not ready.

Comment: @Reactgular Yeah, but this is just an empty container. I guess that doesn't really make much of a difference. If it doesn't have any negative effects I guess this is more up to readability more than anything.

Comment: I'm not sure this post answers the question asked. yes. it correctly explains the main use case for `async` pipe, but that's not what the question is about.